# Infinite loop at sys_timeout() - LWIC/src/core/timeouts.c

Tags: c, arm, embedded, infinite-loop, ethernet

In a Ethernet application, when the communication with the server get lost for nearly 10 minutes, the code gets in a infinite loop at line 244:

`if (t->next == NULL || t->next->time > timeout->time)`

is never true.

Here's the loop:

```
void
sys_timeout(u32_t msecs, sys_timeout_handler handler, void *arg)
#endif /* LWIP_DEBUG_TIMERNAMES */
{
  struct sys_timeo *timeout, *t;
  u32_t now, diff;

  timeout = (struct sys_timeo *)memp_malloc(MEMP_SYS_TIMEOUT);
  if (timeout == NULL) {
    LWIP_ASSERT("sys_timeout: timeout != NULL, pool MEMP_SYS_TIMEOUT is empty", timeout != NULL);
    return;
  }

  now = sys_now();
  if (next_timeout == NULL) {
    diff = 0;
    timeouts_last_time = now;
  } else {
    diff = now - timeouts_last_time;
  }

  timeout->next = NULL;
  timeout->h = handler;
  timeout->arg = arg;
  timeout->time = msecs + diff;
#if LWIP_DEBUG_TIMERNAMES
  timeout->handler_name = handler_name;
  LWIP_DEBUGF(TIMERS_DEBUG, ("sys_timeout: %p msecs=%"U32_F" handler=%s arg=%p\n",
    (void *)timeout, msecs, handler_name, (void *)arg));
#endif /* LWIP_DEBUG_TIMERNAMES */

  if (next_timeout == NULL) {
    next_timeout = timeout;
    return;
  }

  if (next_timeout->time > msecs) {
    next_timeout->time -= msecs;
    timeout->next = next_timeout;
    next_timeout = timeout;
  } else {
    for (t = next_timeout; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
      timeout->time -= t->time;
      if (t->next == NULL || t->next->time > timeout->time) {
        if (t->next != NULL) {
          t->next->time -= timeout->time;
        } else if (timeout->time > msecs) {
          /* If this is the case, 'timeouts_last_time' and 'now' differs too much.
             This can be due to sys_check_timeouts() not being called at the right
             times, but also when stopping in a breakpoint. Anyway, let's assume
             this is not wanted, so add the first timer's time instead of 'diff' */
          timeout->time = msecs + next_timeout->time;
        }
        timeout->next = t->next;
        t->next = timeout;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it depends on what types these variables have and what their initial values are. can you show more of the code?

Comment: When it gets stucked, t->next points to t itself, so it will never be NULL. t->next->time value is 0 somehow in this situation, so it will never be higher then timeout->time

I have edited the question. Now it contains the hole function

Comment: Well if you do have a loop in this linked list than you have to check the logic of your code, this really isn't a place to ask to fix your code. If you have a more concrete question feel free to ask, but debugging is your own responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue for like two days and i just figured out that my main included the MX_LWIP_INIT() twice. After removing one of the calls, everything works fine now!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31257993)